# count dataframe colmn value on specific condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame `df` as below and I want to count how many scores are greater than 10 in `df` score column.

data in dataframe `df` is like :

```
code score   
A    11      
B    9     
c    14    
D    11
```

and as output I want 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum` of boolean mask - count `True`s values like `1`s:

```
out = df['score'].gt(10).sum()
#or
#out = (df['score'] > 10).sum()
print (out)
3
```